# Choice field column not showing on PowerApp Screen

Tags: office-365, choice-field, powerapp

I have created a PowerApp on Office365 from SharePoint list.
In my list there are FirstName(Title), LastName(Text), Department(Choice) fields.

I am able to see FirstName and LastName fields but not Department field. Only Number, Single Line of Text, Date-time fields are showing.

How to display Choice field ? In below picture, I want to display Department which is Choice field and not showing in drop-down.

[image]

It can possible to display on Edit Form Screen as explained here: [Introducing support for lookups and a new sample app](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/support-for-lookups/)

But on the default template form screen, choice fields are not showing.

I have added internal name of the Department field in function (fx), shows error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to bind field value like below.

In below `Sample` is your field's internal name.

`ThisItem.Sample.Value` or `Sample.Value` will also work.

Comment: Thanks,.. `Field.Value` and `ThisItem.Field.Value` both are working... It was so simple.