# How to show a list of filtered item by a specified column in powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

My scenario:

i have a button that navigate to a list of ONLY active cases,right now it is showing all the cases. Note i am filtering by a choice filed in the list called status that has 3 choices:Active,Pending,Closed.Any idea how to filter that list?

Comment: I don't know anything about Powerapps, I had a look at the SE tag description, it was pretty ambiguous. However, this post might be relevant to you: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/202241/choice-field-column-not-showing-on-powerapp-screen You might want to check out other posts tagged as Powerapp too: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powerapp